# use more than one labels

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

In my ASP.NET application I have around 7 to 8 `Label` controls and currently my code to set their `Text` value looks like this:

```
while (MyReader.Read())
{
    if(j>=i && j-i<=10 && j<(10+i+a))
    {
        Label"+[j]+".Text=a;
    }
    j++;
}
```

Now my label name statred from 1 to 8, I dont want to repaeat my statements like:

- label1.text=a;
- label.text=b;

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That actually should resolve your issue:

```
((Label)Page.FindControl("Label" + j)).Text = a;
```

However as Jon suggested, it would be better to manage your labels in more generic way using list or something.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than having seven different variables (`label1`, `label2` etc) have one variable of type `List<Label>` or something similar. Then you can access them by index, iterate over all of them etc.

If you're relying on the designer to declare your variables for you, you could leave them alone but *also* have a collection variable which you populate in one place. The only problem is that then if you reassign the individual variables, that change won't be reflected in your collection.

As an aside, it looks like you've got your presentation logic and your data access logic in one place - you should consider separating them...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while (MyReader.Read())
{
    if(j>=i && j-i<=10 && j<(10+i+a))
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Name="Label" + j;
        lbl.Text = a;
    }
    j++;
}
```